# what is the correct caching directive syntax for mod_expires?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, caching

We're considering using the following caching directive in our .htaccess file

```
ExpiresByType text/html "access"
```

Is that valid syntax? And what does it mean?

My understating (and testing, in 4 major browsers has shown) is that when a client accesses the HTML file, it will remain in it's cache and be pulled from it's cache, until we modify the HTML file on our server, at which time the client will pull the file from our server and use the modified/updated copy.

The [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) docs for mod_expires clearly shows the additional arguments are optional.

Answer (score 1):

> `ExpiresByType text/html "access"`

Well, it's "valid", but this effectively expires the cache instantly (unless there is another caching mechanism in place - see below).

The `ExpiresByType` directive simply controls the `Expires` and `Cache-Control: max-age` headers. The above directive results in the `Expires` header being set to *now* (the current time) and `max-age: 0` - in other words a *zero* cache time.

> when a client accesses the HTML file, it will remain in it's cache and be pulled from it's cache, until we modify the HTML file on our server

This is not related to the `ExpiresByType` directive (as mentioned above), which explicitly states "access", not "modification".

What you are probably seeing is caching as a result of the `Last-Modified` (Response) header and the `If-Modified-Since` (request) headers, but this is quite separate and not controlled by mod_expires.

Comment: Exactly, I'm seeing the if-modified-since header, and I only see that when the ExpiresByType directive is used. Surely altogether it equates to : if-modified-since access time, serve up the latest copy.

Comment: The only difference between "access" and "modification" according to apache is that "access" pertains to the specific browser, whereas "modification" applies to all browsers on the same machine. E.g. if I visit a page using MSIE, then Chrome will see the page as expired at the same time MSIE expires it. Our testing has shown this to be true also.

Comment: The _browser_ sends the `If-Modified-Since` header as part of the _request_ when it has previously cached a server response that had a `Last-Modified` header. Your server sends the `Last-Modified` header as part of the response - but this has nothing to do with mod_expires and the `ExpiresByType` directive. "if-modified-since access time" - that's not the way it works, the server does not know when you last accessed the site. _if-modified-since it was last-modified_ - these two headers are a pair that work together.

Comment: The difference between "access" and "modification" is that for "access", the `Expires` and `max-age` headers are set/calculated based on when the client _accessed_ the document and with "modification" the `Expires` and `max-age` headers are set/calculated based on the last modified date of the document. So, yes, this naturally has the result of effecting just one specific browser or all browsers on all machines, respectively. Note that "modification" only applies to actual files on the filesystem. This won't work for dynamically generated files/pages.